# Dynamically control table style (height, width etc.)

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic, table, style

I want to dynamically control table style (height, width etc.). My approach is as below:

**Controller**

```
public class Cntl_DynamicTableWidth {
    String a{set; get;}
    public Cntl_DynamicTableWidth (){
        a = 'style= "width:100px; height:200px"';
    }
}
```

**VF Page: erroneous**

***Error: DynamicTableWidth line 3, column 10: Element type "table" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Error   Error: Element type "table" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".***

```
<apex:page controller="Cntl_DynamicTableWidth">
  <table {!a} border="1">
      <tr>
        <th Value="firstCol" >firstCol</th>
        <th Value="firstCol" >firstCol1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td Value="firstCol" >firstCol</td>
        <td Value="firstCol" >firstCol</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</apex:page>
```

Here I have used **table**. You may provide solutions with any type of tables like **datatable etc.**

Please let me know how to correct it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing to compile because it doesn't like the standalone `{!a}`, but with a small change it should work:

```
public class Cntl_DynamicTableWidth {
    String a{set; get;}
    public Cntl_DynamicTableWidth (){
        a = 'width:100px; height:200px';
    }
}


<apex:page controller="Cntl_DynamicTableWidth">
  <table style="{!a}" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th Value="firstCol" >firstCol</th>
        <th Value="firstCol" >firstCol1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td Value="firstCol" >firstCol</td>
        <td Value="firstCol" >firstCol</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Only one small change, we need to add PUBLIC:

`public String a{set; get;}`

Now it's working absolutely fine.

**Thanks a ton!**